RandomVariate sometimes returns the input instead of the numbers
Bug introduced in v14.1

I have a series of functions that eventually are combined to form a probability distribution function:
c = 3 10^5;
H0 = 67.4;
\[CapitalOmega] = 0.315;
zmax = 8.;
h[t_?NumericQ] := Sqrt[\[CapitalOmega] (1 + t)^3 + 1 - \[CapitalOmega]]
dp[t_?NumericQ] := (c NIntegrate[1/h[x], {x, 0, t}])/H0
F[t_?NumericQ] := (4 \[Pi] c dp[t]^2)/(H0 h[t])
e1[t_?NumericQ] := 1(* simplest case, but I have other functions with explicit dependence on t; this should work, though*)
P1[z_?NumericQ] := e1[z] F[z]/(1 + z)(* almost a probability function *)
Np01 = 1/NIntegrate[P1[z], {z, 0, zmax}] // Quiet(* normalizing constant for P1*)
prob1 = ProbabilityDistribution[Np01 P1[z], {z, 0, zmax}];(* proper probability function, i.e., normalized to unity*)

and when I want to draw RandomVariates it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't:
RandomVariate[prob1, 100]
RandomVariate[prob1, 100]
RandomVariate[prob1, 100]


How to make it robust? I need 10^5 RandomVariates, which takes a considerable amount of time, so I don't want to wait and see if this particular draw was fine or erroneous.
$Version


"14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"

Works properly in v13.3.1 and v11.1.1.

Cannot reproduce it in 14.1 on Windows 10, trying several times. Maybe, a session depending result. Did you try your code on a fresh kernel (I see Out[65] in the picture.)?

@user64494 I'm on Windows 11, but in a fresh kernel the issue persists.

I executed it just now. Indeed, the third  (not the second for me) execution returned the input.

Since it works properly in previous versions (it works in 14.0!), I would says this could be considered as a regression bug, and you should report it to the WRI.
It seems that the algorithm first "randomly" pokes at your function, and decides whether it is a valid probability distribution. It looks like this source of randomness sometimes leads to Mathematica deciding you have not given it a proper distribution.
As a workaround, you can, for example, construct an interpolation function:
f = Interpolation[Table[{z, Np01 P1[z]}, {z, 0, zmax, 0.001}]];

prob2 = ProbabilityDistribution[f[z], {z, 0, zmax}]

(* The following seems to work consistently *)
RandomVariate[prob2, 100]

